# storing string of an XML document in div, but first line is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Im storing the "NEW STRING" into a div by using the .append() method and then calling it by using the .html() method which is the "OLD STRING" (sorry for the confusion the names may cause). For some reason, it is ommitting the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` line.

[image: Difference in Strings]

Any ideas? Im thinking that it might have something to the  tags because this jQuery is called within a php document. Butt, if its in a string, it shouldn't have any issues right?
Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

html function doesn't work on xml documents.  `.html(data.replace(/</g, '&lt;')); will work or .html(data.text.escapeHTML()) will do too`